# Terminatable Thread Observer

Tags: java, concurrency

There are five slave algorithms and one master algorithm. In each master algorithm's iteration those five slave algorithms work in parallel (they all implement the `Runnable` interface) and when one of them finishes, it notifies others so that they terminate too, and after all of them are finished, the master algorithm begins postprocessing. The notification process is based on the observer pattern. Each slave algorithm implements `Terminatable` interface and has a link to a `TerminationObserver` class that contains a list of runnables and has such a method:

```
 public synchronized void terminateAll() {
    for (Terminatable terminatable : terminatables) {
        if (!terminatable.isTerminated()) {
            terminatable.terminate();
        }
    }
 }
```

Each slave algorithm is a set of iterations, so termination is performed by setting a `terminated` boolean variable to `true` which is a part of stop iterating conditions. Here is the overview of the slave algorithm class:

```
public class SlaveAlgorithm {

   /**
    * Process the algorithm.
    */    
   public void run() {
       try {
           threadBarrier.await();

           while (!stopConditionMet()) {
               performIteration()
           }

           // whether it is terminated by other algorithm or
           // the stop conditions met
           if (!isTerminated()) {  
              terminate();
              terminateOthers();
           }

       } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(new AlgException(e));
       }
   }

   /**
    * Tests whether the algorithms is terminated.
    */
   public boolean isTerminated() {
       return terminated;
   }

   /**
    * Terminates the algorithm execution and
    * causes other algorithms to terminate as well.
    */
   public void terminate() {
       terminated = true;
   }

   /**
    * Removes the current algorithm form the termination observer's list
    * and requests the termination of other algorithms, left in the termination    observer.
    */
   private void terminateOthers() {
       terminationObserver.remove(this); // eliminate the already terminated process from the list
       terminationObserver.terminateAll();
   }
}
```

Everything works fine, but it seem that this is not the "best practice". May be there are some pitfals that I don't see or may be there are some other well-known practices to do things I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should leave the `terminateOthers()` decision making to the `TerminationObserver` instead of `SlaveAlgorithm`. You should have something like this:

```
public class SlaveAlgorithm {
  public void run() {
    try {
      threadBarrier.await();

      while (!stopConditionMet() && !isTerminated()) {
        performIteration()
      }
      done();
    }
    catch ...
  }

  /**
   * If not terminated notify observer the processing is done.
   */
  private void done() {
    if (!isTerminated()) {  
      terminationObserver.notifyDone(this)
    }
  }
```

And the observer should do something like this:

```
public class TerminationObserverImpl {
  private void notifyDone(SlaveAlgorithm slave) {
    remove(slave); // Remove it from the list.
    terminateAll(); // Go through the list and terminate each slave.
  }
  ...
```

Comment: Cebence, thank you for the suggestion! What do you think about   synchronization? It seems that every method in the TerminationObserver class should be synchronized, but I'm not sure about the slave algorithm's methods

Comment: Anything that will be shared among threads should be synchronized. In case of the slave class I think only `terminate()` and `isTerminated()`.

Comment: Ok, I'll do the refactoring. Thank you!